# Is it possible to save a containers.Map object to a variable in the MATLAB C Engine API?

Tags: matlab

I've been happily using haskell-matlab (a wrapper for Haskell around the C Engine API for MATLAB), but when trying to simply save a containers.Map value to a variable in Haskell,  I get the error:

```
Unable to save variable 'hseval_out1' of class 'containers.Map' to STDIO.
```

I apologize for not including C code, but if there is a working solution in C, I can translate that to Haskell.

Comment: Possible that container.Map is not part of the C API, I don't think it is supported for code generation either.

Comment: `containers.Map` is a custom class (meaning it is defined in an M-file using `classdef`), and therefore unlikely to be supported in C. The mx... interface has functions to work with such objects, but you would need to write that code yourself, it will not be pre-made for you by MATLAB.

Comment: OK, thanks. The problematic function seems to be `engGetVariable`; this reference seems to back up what you are saying: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102626-can-i-use-enggetvariable-or-mexgetvariable-to-retrieve-objects-in-matlab-7-0-r14